# In a curved position

Tags: meaning

Can I say;

> Keep your neck in a position that is curved forward.

Instead of

> Keep your neck in a position in which it is curved forward.

In the first sentence it sounds “that” suggests that the position itself is curved, not the neck but what I couldn’t understand is that when we say “in a curved position” “curved” modifies “position” it means position itself curved and in my phrase” in a position that is curved” “curved” modifies “position” in the same way. I couldn’t understand why we can’t say in a position that is curved while saying in a curved position.

Comment: lean your head forward and keep this position ?

Comment: Bend your neck forward.

Answer (score 4):

Either one would be understood.

Better would be to simplify further and say something like, "keep your neck curved forward".

Answer (score -2):

I would say "curved" in this context is not idiomatic. The correct word to use is "bowed". So the correct phrasing would be:

> Keep your neck bowed.

Comment: All my teacher and other native speaker whom I asked could easily understand what I tried to say but I can’t understood how you concluded I am enforcing subjection. Thanks for this interesting answer.

Comment: @language learner: Because often 'bowing a neck' means exactly that as well as oppression, bondage and enslavement.